# Partial text-formatted date match with Elasticsearch regexp

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-py, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I formatted a date field `dob` as text `dob.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")` and stored these dates on Elasticsearch 8.7.1 (`"lucene_version": "9.5.0"`) so I could utilize `regexp` to do partial date matching.

Suppose this date is stored on Elasticsearch: `06/01/2023`, I noticed that I was only able to get this result back when using these regexp queries:

- `06.*`
- `.*01.*`
- `.*2023`

However, using `/` or `\/` or `\\/` in the query couldn't get back any result. Double checked on [Elasticsearch's doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/regexp-syntax.html), `/` is NOT a reserved character.

I have a few questions, help would be much appreciated:

1. Why is `/` not working as a part of the `regexp` query?
2. How to correctly formulate the `regexp` query? I wish I could find matches after typing a term that's matching any of the following format:

```
- M/d
- M/d/YY
- M/d/YYYY
- M/dd
- M/dd/YY
- M/dd/YYYY
- M/YY
- M/YYYY
- MM/d
- MM/d/YY
- MM/d/YYYY
- MM/dd
- MM/dd/YY
- MM/dd/YYYY
- MM/YY
- MM/YYYY
```

3. Does any other types of search work better than `regexp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_reserved_characters), `/` is indeed a reserved character. When using JSON for the request body, two preceding backslashes (\) are required since the backslash is a reserved escaping character in JSON strings.

`regexp` query works differently for text and keyword fields. Elasticsearch analyzes fields before applying regex. [Text fields are tokenized into individual words](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analyzer-anatomy.html) so using `/` couldn't find any match.

Instead, the entire keyword field string is treated as a single and non-analyzed string (see [Keyword analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.8/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html)). Searching with `/` and regexp worked after I used a keyword field instead:

- `dob = fields.TextField(fields={"raw": fields.KeywordField()})`

```
"mappings": {
  "properties": {
    "dob": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "raw": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
 }
```

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "dob.raw": ".*6\\/.*2023.*"
    }
  }
}
```